# Query that works on difference of dates

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider I have a doc which has `createdDate` and `closedDate`. Now I want to find all docs where `(closedDate - createdDate) > 2`. I am not able to apply script in range field. Any clue how to proceed with this.
I think this may be possbile by using scripts. By isn't any way I can perform this by query.

Isn't a way to perform this like

```
{
    "range" : {
        "date" : {
            "gt" :  "{createdDate} - {closedDate}/d > 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that by query is to index an additonal duration field before-hand into your JSON document. Personally I would store the duration in milliseconds and use filters for queries.

If this is not acceptable you will have to use script fields. Described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) in the Elasticsearch docu.

IMO saving the durtion to each document is preferable, especially if you frequently use the duration for further analysis. The additional field does not cost a lot of memory, but reduces the need for calculations (and therefore is likly to speed up query time) And Especially in Elasticsearch memory shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: I was thinking about that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this via script

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "(doc.closedDate.value - doc.createdDate.value)/86400000 > 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order to try this.

However, it'd be best to already compute that difference at indexing time and then use a range query on that difference field.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of storing a field at indexing time

Comment: Would be better, indeed. Anything you need at search time and you know you can compute at indexing time, you should do.